# insert ... select with divide operator in select errors?

Tags: mysql, select, insert, mysql-error-1064, division

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS XY (
     x INT NOT NULL ,
     y FLOAT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY(x)
    )

```
INSERT INTO XY (x,y)
(select 1 as x ,(1/7) as y);
```

errors with

```
Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO XY (x,y)
(select 1 as x ,(1/7) as y)' at line 7
Line 1, column 1
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add **;** after `CREATE TABLE` statement (or before `INSERT` statement) . You are trying to execute 2 different queries without separator.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS XY (
x INT NOT NULL ,
y FLOAT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY(x)
);  # !!! Originally, you missed ;

INSERT INTO XY (x,y)
(select 1 as x ,(1/7) as y);
```

Comment: this was an attempt at finding out why this query is not working,
INSERT INTO resultprobability (ballNumber, probability)
(select resultset.ballNumber ballNumber,(count(0)/(select count(0) from resultset)) probability
  from resultset
  group by resultset.ballNumber);

Answer (score 0):

do you need the parentheses around the select statement

```
INSERT INTO XY (x,y)
select 1 as x ,(1/7) as y;
```